# three.js applying texture to stl mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am loading a STL exported from Rhino. All works ok, however, when I try and apply a simple texture to the mesh, the STL objects are not rendered at all.

What am I missing

Code is as follows:

```
var diamondTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/diamond.jpg');
...
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    var geometry = event.content;
    stones = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x99CC3B, ambient:0x99CC3B, map:diamondTexture}) );

    scene.add( stones );

} );
loader.load( 'models/jwl0020-stones.stl' );
```

Comment: The problem is that, as far as I know, STL don't store UVs. We don't have a UV generator yet so you'll have to create them on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could try geometry.computeTangents(). Once I added that my stl files were able to have a texture though... the texture does not not properly "fit" the model since there are no UVs.